# How to download Windows 8 app without Windows app store

Tags: windows-8-apps

My music app in Window 8 is not working, it says "Your app need an update" and it says download this update from app store.

So I enter the app store but the app store says it is not available at our location (Myanmar, our country has a very very slow Internet connection.)

In this case what should I do to get my music app back? When I download the update app from microsoft site , I get one but it can't down load directly without using Windows app store

Comment: Has the Windows Store ever worked for you?

Comment: I wonder if updating these things though a proxy might help - tunnelbear might let you test on a small scale for free, though I doubt the free tier would let you download say, windows 8.1

Answer (score 3):

### You Can't

The application in question can only be updated through the `Windows Store`. If it was your own application that is another story.

Answer (score 3):

Download AND Install Windows 8 Apps
Without The Windows Store
Easy Steps
Let's Start

1-Download AND Install Fiddler http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler

2-Open Fiddler AND Click on Win8 Config

3-Click Exempt All Then Save Changes

4-Open Windows Store AND Find Your App to Download Then Click Install

5-Go To Desktop AND As You Can See Fiddler Is Finding Download URL of Your App

6-Right Click on The Download Arrow Icon And Click on Just Copy Then URL

7-Past It on Any Download Manager

8-After We Download Our App Now We Need To Install It

9-Open Windows Powershell

10-Type in The Powershell add-appxpackage yourapp.zip or appx if you changed
The Type of the File from zip to appx file

Example

add-appxpackage C:\WinApps\Facebook.zip

add-appxpackage C:\WinApps\Facebook.appx

or
add-appxpackage Facebook.zip
add-appxpackage Facebook.appx
if you copy and past windows powerershell in the folder like C:\WinApps\

11-Check if Your App Installed or Not

Answer (score 1):

There is one simple answer to your question. No. All of the apps on the windows store are downloaded from the store, updated through the store, and deleted from the store. There is no inbetween.